# jQuery innerWidth minus height not working on 'if else' on smaller devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I can written a bit of code that allows me to set the Window height on both large and low resolution devices, this allows me to center the content in the middle of the device using Flexbox.

I'm detecting the smaller screen by using `if (window.innerWidth >= 1023) {` and `} else {`, this works wonders on the home page on both big and smaller devices. However the `.flexAligner` seems to be setting the 'height' but ignoring `- 88`, again this only develops on pages that are not the home page, i.e without `.home .intro`

I can't wrap my head around why its not working correct, hopefully someone can point out why `- 88` it is not working. I think its something to do with the fact that the Vegas Slider is refreshing the element while the later isn't.

*Short snippet what's not working:*

```
} else {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .home .intro').css('min-height', windowHeight - 88);
```

*Full code here:*

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 1023) {
      windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
      $('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .vegas-container, .justHeight').css('min-height', windowHeight);
      $("body.home").vegas({
        delay: 8000,
        transition: 'fade',
        transitionDuration: 8e3,
        timer: false,
        slides: [
          { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide-01-desktop.jpg" },
          { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide-02-desktop.jpg" },
          { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide-03-desktop.jpg" }
        ],
        animation: "kenburns"
      });
      $(".home .intro").vegas('destroy');
    } else {
      windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
      $('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .home .intro').css('min-height', windowHeight - 88);
      $(".home .intro").vegas({
        delay: 8000,
        transition: 'fade',
        transitionDuration: 8e3,
        timer: false,
        cover: false,
        slides: [
          { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide-01-mobile.jpg" },
          { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide-02-mobile.jpg" },
          { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide-03-mobile.jpg" }
        ],
        animation: "fade"
      });
      $("body.home").vegas('destroy');
    }
  }).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
else {
windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
$('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .home .intro').css('min-height', (windowHeight - 88));
```

I added parenthesis to group the 88 with the windowHeight